# Unable to make scyllaDB keyspace and table while creating scylladb container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, scylla

I'm trying to make keyspace and table while creating scyllaDB container. For this I'm making a script file 'my_schema.sh':

```
CREATE KEYSPACE IF NOT EXISTS books_keyspace WITH replication = 
{'class':'SimpleStrategy','replication_factor':'1'};

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS books_keyspace.books
(
book_id int PRIMARY KEY, 
book_name text, 
genre text, 
price double, 
issue_date text, 
return_date text, 
fine double
)
```

Then I add this as entrypoint in docker-compose:

```
version: "3"

services:

  scyllaDB-node1:
    container_name: scyllaDB-node1
    image: scylladb/scylla:5.1.0
    restart: always
    command: --smp 1 --memory 750M --overprovisioned 1 --api-address 0.0.0.0
    entrypoint: ["/my_schema.sh"]
    volumes:
      - ./my_schema.sh:/my_schema.sh
```

But when I run this command:

```
docker compose -f script-docker-compose.yaml up -d

docker exec -it scyllaDB-node1 nodetool status
```

It gives the following error:

```
Error response from daemon: Container 44b7e04d61917444ceaaaec9135891c66355dffbf1b5f39c352f465db85ea08e is restarting, wait until the container is running
```

On checking logs:

```
docker logs scyllaDB-node1 

Creating keyspace and table...
/my_schema.sh: line 11: CREATE: command not found
/my_schema.sh: line 12: class:SimpleStrategy: command not found
/my_schema.sh: line 14: CREATE: command not found
/my_schema.sh: line 16: book_id: command not found
/my_schema.sh: line 17: book_name: command not found
/my_schema.sh: line 18: genre: command not found
/my_schema.sh: line 19: price: command not found
/my_schema.sh: line 20: issue_date: command not found
/my_schema.sh: line 21: return_date: command not found
/my_schema.sh: line 22: fine: command not found
```

Kindly help me, how can I make keyspace and table while creating container in docker-compose. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of problems with your approach.

First, you are not providing a script, but rather CQL statements. You want to execute these statements using the `cqlsh` `-e` or `-f` flags.

`-e` will accept a regular CQL statement; whereas
`-f` will accept a file to read the CQL statements from

The second problem of your approach is that you are defining the *script* in question (which, as we saw in the above pointer is not really a script) as a container entrypoint. Which means that once your script finishes, the container will die, and as you are using docker-compose it will try to restart it.

In general, you do not want to override the entrypoint. The ScyllaDB container uses *supervisord* as the entrypoint by default, which makes it easily customizable.

Therefore, the right way to define a program to be executed when your container starts is by placing a supervisord service definition under the `/etc/supervisord.conf.d` folder, which then calls the script or program you want.

However, this approach brings a third problem: The fact that your service will now be executed everytime your service starts. This may not typically be a problem, but in your case it might be, specially as you are running a distributed database.

The right way to automate your schema creation, therefore, would be from an application perspective and, in particular, take a look at schema migration tools (such as [gocqlx migrate](https://github.com/scylladb/gocqlx/tree/master/migrate), or [cassandra-migrate](https://github.com/Cobliteam/cassandra-migrate)), for example, which are made exactly for that purpose.